# Typescript recursive object type

Tags: typescript

I want to define a `type`/`interface` that is able to contain properties of the same type as itself.

**For Example:**

```
    type TMessagesFormat = { [key: string]: string };
    
    interface TMessages {
      messages: TMessagesFormat;
    }
    
    interface TGroupMessages {
      messages?: TMessagesFormat;
      controls: { [key: string]: TMessages | TGroupMessages }
    }
    
    let groupMessages: TGroupMessages = {
      controls: {
        username: { messages: {required: 'Username required'} }
      }
    }
    
    let messages: TGroupMessages = {
      controls: {
        username: { messages: { required: 'Username required' } },
        passwordGroup: {
          messages: { nomatch: 'Passwords doesn\'t match' },
          controls: {
            password: { messages: { required: 'Password required' } }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Type checking works fine for username and passwordGroup, but e.g controls in passwordGroup can be anything and TS compiler doesn't complain. In fact if I put `controls: 'whatever'` property (string shouldn't be a valid type) inside `username` object literal, code still compiles without any warning or error. Is this possible and how? Thanks!

Comment: Guess there is an implicit type assertion. let x : TMessages = {
        messages: {required: ''}, controls: 1
    }; // throw error
    let y = {
        messages: {required: ''}, controls: 1
    } as TMessages; // works well

Comment: Things changed over about 2 1/2 years ago, where you can define recursive-types  much easier. I've included an example in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is [a bug in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22129) where excess property checks on object literals don't seem to happen for unions the way you'd expect.  The shortest reproduction:

```
interface A {
    a: string;
}
interface B {
    b: number;
}
const a: A = {a: 'dog', b: 'cat'}; // error, b is unknown property
const ab: A | B = {a: 'dog', b: 'cat'}; // no error!
```

You would expect `ab` to error with something like `'cat' is not a number`, but it doesn't because of the above issue. If and when that issue gets addressed, your problem should go away.

---

But we don't have to wait.  The fact is that excess property checking on object literals isn't *very* protective.  It just warns you if you add an unknown property to a ["fresh"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/freshness.html) object literal.  In TypeScript there's nothing really wrong with adding extra properties to an object.  If an object is a valid `A`, that same object is still a valid `A` even if you add extra properties to it.  So if you do something to evade the excess property checking (e.g., assign a "non-fresh" literal to it), you're allowed to add any extra properties you want.

```
const dogCat = {a: 'dog', b: 'cat'};
const a: A  = dogCat; // no error
```

What if you really want to disallow extra properties?  Well, there's no [general way](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) to do it for all properties.  But if you want to disallow *particular* extra properties and know their key names, there's a way to do it:

```
interface A {
    a: string;
    b?: never; // cannot have a defined b
}
interface B {
    b: number;
}
const dogCat = {a: 'dog', b: 'cat'};
const a: A  = dogCat; // error, string is not undefined
const ab: A | B = {a: 'dog', b: 'cat'}; // error, string is not number
```

Now you get errors for both non-fresh `a` and `ab`.  So, back to your case...

---

If we can assume that `TMessages` *cannot* have a `controls` property:

```
interface TMessages {
  messages: TMessagesFormat;
  controls?: never; // no defined controls
}

interface TGroupMessages {
  messages?: TMessagesFormat;
  controls: { [key: string]: TMessages | TGroupMessages }
}
```

Then, if a `TMessages | TGroupMessages` has a defined `controls` property, it must be of the type specified in `TGroupMessages`:

```
let tm: TMessages | TGroupMessages = {messages: {foo: 'hey'}, controls: 3}
// error, 'number' not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: TMessages | TGroupMessages }'
```

And that should work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

---

### TL;DR

Wait for [Microsoft/TypeScript#22129](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22129) to be addressed, or change your `TMessages` interface to the following:

```
interface TMessages {
  messages: TMessagesFormat;
  controls?: never; // no defined controls
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 3.7 this become more of a reality than it was before. IMO TypeScript was to strict at first, but I would imagine from the perspective of the person(s) engineering the langauge, that it would be better to make it too strict, and then loosen up the language, where it made sense to do so, or where it had to be, which is exactly what happened in `TS v3.7`. [The typescript compiler was adjusted to be more loose](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases), allowing references to types that occur in themselves.

---

###### I could give you all sorts of examples, but I think the best, would be to demonstrate how loosely you could recursively define your types now

```
type TMessagesFormat = { [key: string]: TMessagesFormat };

interface TMessages extends TMessagesFormat{
   [key: string]: TMessagesFormat;
}

interface TGroupMessages {
   messages?: TMessagesFormat;
   controls: { [key: string]: TMessages | TGroupMessages };
}
```

**The Above is 100% Legal TypeScript**